# Can't connect to this network Windows 10

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, wireless-router

I have an Edimax wireless dongle that I'm forced to use as my NIC because of a genius wiring job in my apartment. Until recently I've had no problems connecting to my router which is hooked up to my cable modem. All of the leasing is DHCP it's a Belkin 750N dual band router. I've rolled back drivers, updated drivers, uninstalled the device,forgotten saved networks, and tested it on other machines (where it works swimmingly). I can use it in the problem machine to connect to my phone's wireless hotspot so the problem seems to be in the router to dongle connection. Yes, I've restarted my router and modem (which are working fine with every other wireless device I use). This is NOT a no internet connectivity problem - I can't even get a lease. Please help before I lose my mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity does it work if you assign a static IP in the proper range?

Is this a new Windows 10 install/upgrade?

Try opening elevated cmd and doing first
netsh winsock reset catalog [enter]
then
netsh int ip reset reset.log[enter]
Reboot

This will clear out anything left over, cause obviously something is interfering here.

Comment: I successfully reset the TCP/UDP stack using netsh reset catalog. I had to edit permissions using run <regedit> > localmachine > hardware > currentcontrolset > control > NSI > (ee... > 26 > properties > <check> allow full access, but then successfully reset the two TCP/IP registry files (netsh int ip reset reset.log). I set a static IP in the local range using network and sharing center > change adapter settings > <adapter name> > properties > IPv4.  This installation of Windows 10 has been running for about 5 months.

Comment: Still working to solve this problem. I've started to occasionally connect to the network and the internet. I've also started randomly BSODing on restart to a DRIVER_POWER_STATE failure error. After checking out event logs and looking at .dmp files, which suggest an inability to close/open UDP ports and connect to DNS servers (when I'm on the network). I'm still assuming this is a driver issue - will retest and update.

Comment: `netsh winsock reset` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've just uninstalled the Network card, an ASUS PCE-N15 11n, and 
reinstalled it, 
choosing for the OS to search for a driver via Windows update. 
Restarted.
Running Win10 Pro Version 1809 OS build 17763.437, the problem seems to be fixed.

Answer (score -2):

I had this same issue with a fresh install of win10 pro. I eventually got the edimax 7811un to accept my secured wifi network, by simply uninstalling the edimax drivers.

In device manager, uninstalled nano USB adapter and moved the edimax to another USB slot. Uninstalled edimax drivers and it connected.

Comment: How did you accomplish it?  Provide specifics